# jQuery dynamically created datepicker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I already did what most of the solutions I see but it doesn't work on mine.

Here's my code:

```
function regenerateDatePickers()
{
  var length = $( ".forduplication" ).length;
  alert( length );
  for ( var i = 1 ; i <= length ; i++ ) {
    $( "#endDate" + i ).removeClass( "hasDatepicker" );
    $( "#endDate" + i ).datepicker();
  }
}
```

Only the original datepicker field is working. The cloned ones are not.
The Weird thing though is that my dynamically created "chosen"* fields are working.

*chosen http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

EDIT
 - Added HTML code

```
<tr class="forduplication">
  <td>
    ...
    ...<!--lots of other HTML codes-->
    ...
  </td>
  <td><input id="endDate1" name="endDatefield1" size="10"></td>
  ...
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you please paste in your html or set up a fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/), so we can test there? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update 06/01/15

.live() is not longer supported. Using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) this can be solved.

```
$('body')
        .on('click', '.datePick', function() {
            $(this).datepicker();
        })
        .on('focus', '.datePick', function() {
            $(this).datepicker();
        });
```

---

You could use [live](http://jqapi.com/#p=live) and [focusin](http://jqapi.com/#p=focusin)

Have a class for all the input fields, in this case I used `datePick` as the class

```
$('input.datePick').live('focusin', function() {
    $(this).datepicker();
});​
```

Hope this helps

Comment: What's the difference between `focusin` and `focus`?

Comment: focusin supports event bubbling and focus doesn't

Comment: It works thanks, but I still don't understand why my code does not work when I think it perfectly legit

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to destroy and reassign datepicker on every click but it has performence issue

```
$('input[id^="endDate"]').live('click', function() {
    $(this).datepicker('destroy').datepicker({showOn:'focus'}).focus();
});
```

it works but remove and add datepicker every time you click on a input. So it's bettter if you can do this just after cloning the input like

```
....clone().datepicker('destroy').datepicker({showOn:'focus'});
```

and then add that element to where you want it to be.